# On click event only firing once JQuery / bPopup

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am making a web app in ASP.NET MVC that gets information from a website, puts it in a database table and displays it as a table element in HTML. On the last column of the table of every row is a click event, that uses bPopup to pop up a window that essentially summarizes the contents of that particular row. Here is the table and pop up event. **EDIT** JS Fiddle Link instead of picture of table: https://jsfiddle.net/vajwcy6y/3/

[Popup event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jEJY.png)

This click event only occurs once. Because the contents of the table are dynamic, I use a loop to render the HTML, with the last `<td>` being a `button` with `id = "my-button@(counter)"`, and a `<div>` right next to it with `id=whisper@(counter)`, `class="popup"`, show here (at the bottom)

```
<table id ="mytable"class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IGN)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.currencyType)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.currencyAmount)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.itemName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.uri)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@{int counter = 0; }
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    counter += 1;

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IGN)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.currencyAmount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.currencyType)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.uri)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a id="my-button@(counter)" href="#" class="btn btn-large">
               <i class="fa fa-reply-all"></i>Whisper Player</a>
            <div id="whisper@(counter)" class="popup">

            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I then call the script at the end of the page like so:

```
<script>createPopup(@(counter))</script>
<script>assignPopup(@(counter))</script>
```

Which does this:

```
function createPopup(counter) {

for (var i = 0 ; i <= counter; i++) {

    var intro = 'To whisper this player copy and paste this line:@';

    var nameSelector = $("#mytable tr:eq(" + i + ") td:first-child").text();

    var messageStart = 'Hi, I would like to buy your ';

    var itemName = $("#mytable tr:eq(" + i + ") td:nth-child(4)").text();

    var price = ' listed for ' + $("#mytable tr:eq(" + i + ") td:nth-child(2)").text() + ' ' + $("#mytable tr:eq(" + i + ") td:nth-child(3)").text();

    $('#whisper' + i).append(intro + nameSelector + messageStart + itemName + price);
}
};

function createCallback(i) {
return function () {
    $(this).parent().find('#whisper' + i).bPopup();
   }
}

function assignPopup(counter) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= counter; i++)
    {
        $('#my-button' + i).on('click', createCallback(i));

    }
};
```

My reasoning behind this JS is to dynamically assign on `click events`. It seems wonky, but it halfway works.

Here is my CSS

```
.popup { font-family: "Open Sans",Calibri,Candara,Arial,sans-serif;
         background-color:#fff;
         border-radius:15px;
         color:#000;
         display:none; 
         padding:20px;
         width:500px;
         min-height: 180px;}
```

What I've noticed ultimately, is that the `<div>` contents on the last row are rendering correctly, but when I click it, it gains inline CSS styling, and moves to the bottom of the HTML code. I suspect this is the issue, but I'm not 100% sure. I would post images, but I don't have enough reputation to show this.

Thanks for reading such a long post, I want to be thorough.

Comment: Instead of images, try a JSFiddle. Thats easier for us to fix.

Comment: Ok, working on that now.

Comment: Here is a link to the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vajwcy6y/3/

Comment: I upvoted previously, it tells me it wont be public until I gain 15 reputation. Didn't know about the accept answer feature. If there is anything else I need to know to give you credit for this let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer:**
There is not much you need to change:

```
function createCallback(i) {
    return function () {
        $('#whisper' + i).bPopup();
    }
}
```

**The reason:**
When you `bPopup()` some `jquery` object, `bPopup` takes that element and **moves** it. How nasty is that?

It does not move it back to where it once was, though.

This means that after you fire your event once, your `btn.parent` no longer contains the element you were looking for. Instead, its at the bottom of your page.

Therefore, you have to find the element globally. Because you search for an `id` tag, and not a `class` tag, looking for it in the body tag might even make it more efficient because you have less methods to go through (`element.parent().find()` etc.), but I didnt check.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vajwcy6y/7/

Comment: randy, I really appreciate your time. This is great!